Which way should the power order be?
So, assume that we need to solve for x for a given equation,

$2^{3^{4^x}} = 516$

Now, here $x = {1}/{2}$ (when going down to up, by factorising $512$, and equating the powers)
but what if we went up to down instead of down to up?
meaning we do $2^3$ first, instead of $4^x$ , where $x = 1/2$
I know this sounds like a pathetic baby question, but just a small doubt I had in the back of my peanut sized brain.
if possible, also show as to WHY we go down to up instead of it being reversed.
thanks :)

See Henning Makholm's answer to the linked question in particular. As you observed $a^{(b^c)}$ is different from $(a^b)^c$. So we need to pick one of those to be the meaning of $a^{b^c}$. As we (assume integers only to avoid complications) have
$$(a^b)^c=a^{b\cdot c},$$
we have a way of rewriting the latter alternative more simply already. Therefore the former meaning is standard. May be better to call it a widely used convention?
Anyway, in calculus and probability you see a lot of expressions like
$$e^{-x^2/2},$$ where it is imperative that the exponent is evaluated first. This fits.
